# VBA - Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

I have this script I'm using for an inventory list.
For every product there is a count and a reorder limit. If the count is less than the reorder limit, I send an email asking to order more.

I tried running the script, it gave me a compile error. `Subscript out of range - Run-time error9`

Here is my code.

```
  Sub sendEmail()
'
' sendEmail Macro
'

'
    Dim olApp As Object, olMail As Object
    Dim MyData
    Dim i As Long

    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")


    ' ~~> I have taken 70 rows
    MyData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HDD").Range("D2:E70")

    For i = LBound(MyData) To UBound(MyData) - 1
        If MyData(i, 5) > MyData(i, 4) Then
            Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)


            Debug.Print MyData(i, 2)

            With olMail
                .To = "myemail@example.com"
                .Subject = "Sent from Excel"
                .Body = MyData(i, 2)
                .Send
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

My worksheet looks like this:

```
No - Product - Description - Count - Reorder 
---------------------------------------------
1    Pen          -            4        5
```

Comment: When you debug what value is i?  Is it zero or 'empty' on the first pass?

Comment: +1 just because I like those `~~>` fancy comment arrows :)

Comment: @PortlandRunner i = 1;

Comment: @RBarryYoung thanks.. If u type what u said as an answer. I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your array's source range only has two columns, but you are referencing hard-coded column values of 4 and 5 in your array.

Comment: If i want to send the No with the name in the body do I just go  MyData(i, 2) And MyData(i, 1)?

Comment: what name? do you mean product name?

Comment: Yes, currently, I am just sending the name... But I want to include "No" in the body as well. e.g Pen - 1

Comment: Ampersand (`&`) is VB's string concatenation operator.  So it'd be something like `MyData(i, 2) & MyData(i, 1)`.